# Wordpress Classic Themes vs Block Themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Since WordPress 5.9 Block themes are now a part of the WordPress ecosystem. I don't have any experience developing block themes but WordPress says they are built for the newer functionality and can give users more control over the entire site.

Does this mean that the regular **Classic themes** are going to be replaced by newer **Block themes**? Isn't it useful to learn to develop Classic themes anymore or will theme developers have to switch develop block themes?

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: This kind of questions are hard to answer because no one knows what the future holds. IMO we'll keep working with the two types of themes -classic and block base ones- for the foreseeable future so I wouldn't worry about that __now__. It might be a good idea to learn how to create block themes at some point though as I'm sure you'll be needing these skills (if you want to keep working as a WP developer that is).

Comment: Sahan, I think since block themes are based on HTML templates, they seem to be more secure than classic themes based on PHP templates. See the list of differences and similarities: [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes#differences-and-similarities-between-classic-themes-and-block-themes)